# Illustrator proper overlap of shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, borders

I am trying to use Pathfinder `shape modes` to cut out parts of shape and overlay them on each other (as shown in following figure)

[image]

However, I am getting shape overlapping with border of background shape (see arrow in figure). For now, I am manually resizing overlay so that background borders are visible. However, this process is highly inefficient once shape become more complex. Is there way to properly achieve this so that I can use `shape mode` from Pathfinder and still able to see background border properly?

Comment: As long as the top object doesn't have a stroke of its own, you could change the stroke of the bottom object `Window > Stroke` → `Align Stroke: Outside`.

Comment: @Joonas, this is the exact effect I was hopping for. Thank you. Put this as an answer for future designer.

Comment: Done and done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You can alter your workflow in a small way and its nolonger a problem. Remember what you are doing is a model of how things ought to work. There are many situations where the model fails you. Dont be afraid to alter your model.

There are 2 approaches to this.

- Use strokes that are outside the object (Window > Stroke → Align Stroke: Outside)
- copy the shapes behind kill their fill and put the copies on a layer above.

Answer (score 2):

### Make a Clipping Mask

- Select the circle and send it back
- Select both shapes
- **Menu Object** > **Clipping Mask** > **Make**
- **Direct Selection Tool** > click the mask edge
- Fill it and add a stroke color and width

[image]

Comment: I thought of including clipping paths in answer but then decided not to because the op said more complex and pathfinder. Im not sure it scales to the more complex.